# Fragment is not fully displayed in Activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

In my app I have an Activity containing a simple container (LinearLayout) in which I want to display a Fragment. It all works and the fragment is shown but it is kind of "cut off" at the end of the screen. Meaning if in the fragment the screen is completely filled out with buttons, in the actual running app the last button is not or only partly shown.

To make it easier to test I created this new project where in the fragment there are only 3 big buttons which, in the design function in android studio, do not extend the screen but then when I run it are cut off.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BlankFragment">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textSize="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textSize="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textSize="70dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.51"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button9" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"/>
```

```
package com.example.fragmenttestapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;



public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    }

}
```

```
package com.example.fragmenttestapp;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Would appreciate some help! :)

Comment: For fragments linear layouts are not ideal. Better use frame layout or relative layout

Comment: Ok thanks but the problem stays also with frame or relative layout..any ideas?

Comment: Add in mainactivity Linearlayout mlinear = findviewbyId(. r.id.container);

Comment: Where exactly and what should that change? Also I think you mean LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.container); ? But I do not see what this changes

Comment: Remove blank fragment

Comment: remove from where exactly?

Comment: From mainactivity. Where you wrote new blank fragment

Comment: but how else would I add the fragment to the activity then?

Comment: Add fragment transaction.replace rather than fragment transaction.add in mainactivity

Comment: 1. Then I would still need the blank fragment
2. This doesnt change anything

Comment: One more suggestion try to add another layout inside activity main linear layout and name it container.

Comment: Rather than working on parent layout

Comment: also doesnt work :(

Answer (score 0):

I am 99% sure that your views are not fitting into your screen because of your huge text size on your views (`100dp`), large text size will resize your view, and you are using a fixed size for you texts size.
Remember that **fixed size on views makes your layout non-responsive**

After I removed your text size from the views it was alright, here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button10"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="w"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button9" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And if you want to use large text maybe use [Autosizing TextViews](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview)

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I only made the huge text so I don't have to put so many buttons but the problem stays the same when I don't change the text size but instead just add buttons in the xml design until this screen is filled up. 
Somehow the code you posted doesnt work for me, its complaining about the  inflating class android.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout..can you help? Thanks!

Comment: In general, what should I use instead of fixed sizes? Also for normal text views or images if I want them to be displayed in a certain size?

Comment: In general, what should I use instead of fixed sizes - I think that constraintLayout with guidelines is good. and for your first post, try only to copy what's inside the constraint layout into your layout